# Flexbox leave one element above and two below without changing HTML

Tags: html, css

I have simple divs like these:

```css
.container {
  width: 20rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

This makes it so that child 1 and child 2 are above, and child 3 is below centered. My question is, without changing the HTML structure, is there any way to make it so that the child 1 is above centered, and child 2 and child 3 are below?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `*-reverse` and update the orders:

```css
.container {
  width: 20rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
}

.child:nth-last-child(1) {order: 1;}
.child:nth-last-child(2) {order: 2;}
.child:nth-last-child(3) {order: 3;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: intresting solutions. if more child elemnts are used, can the code be simplified or does it need JS for giving them the correct flex order without hard coding?

Comment: @tacoshy you can use less/sass to generate the code since the pattern is easy `.child:nth-last-child(i) {order: i;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `first-child` selector

```css
.container{
    width: 20rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.child{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.child:first-child {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="child">1</div>
   <div class="child">2</div>
   <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-right` or `margin-left` or both (to keep symmetry) to the first element:

```
.child:first-child {
     margin: 0 1px;  /* or 50%, whichever is less */
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 20rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.child:first-child {
  margin: 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
</div>
```